# ERROR in using Gradle for flutter in VScode and Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle, visual-studio-code

This problem arrises when i run my first flutter program in vscode and java both
cachex.pdn.ac.lk is an proxy address used earlier but now it is removed in pc settings and app settings. thank you!

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
  >   cachex.pdn.ac.lk
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom'.
  >   cachex.pdn.ac.lk
  >   Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
  >   cachex.pdn.ac.lk
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Is your firewall blocking vscode for some reason?

Comment: provide app/build.gradle

Comment: No the error was in java version. I roll back my java version to java 8

Answer (score 0):

Error is with java version. I have rolled it back to java 8 and got it working